# Azure - Unable to change network security group using Ansible

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible, ansible-2.x

When I'm trying to update the Network security group of a interface, I get the following error.

`"msg": "value of public_ip_allocation_method must be one of: Dynamic, Static, got: None found in ip_configurations"`.

I checked the Azure VM Network Config and there is a public IP set. I also tested by creating a new IP and set the assignment to be `Dynamic` but still I got the same error as above.

[image]

Ansible Code:

```
  - name: Applying NSG to target NIC
    azure_rm_networkinterface:
      name: "{{ azure_vm_network_interface }}"
      resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
      subnet_name: "{{ azure_network_interface_info.networkinterfaces[0].subnet }}"
      virtual_network: "{{ azure_network_interface_info.networkinterfaces[0].virtual_network.name }}"
      ip_configurations: "{{ azure_network_interface_info.networkinterfaces[0].ip_configurations }}"
      security_group: "/subscriptions/123456/resourceGroups/test-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/testing_temp_8"
```

Error:

```
                            "ip_configurations": [
                                {
                                    "application_gateway_backend_address_pools": null,
                                    "application_security_groups": null,
                                    "load_balancer_backend_address_pools": null,
                                    "name": "Ubuntu915",
                                    "primary": true,
                                    "private_ip_address": "10.0.0.5",
                                    "private_ip_address_version": "IPv4",
                                    "private_ip_allocation_method": "Dynamic",
                                    "public_ip_address": "/subscriptions/123456789/resourceGroups/test-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/Ubuntu-915-test",
                                    "public_ip_address_name": "/subscriptions/123456789/resourceGroups/test-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/Ubuntu-915-test",
                                    "public_ip_allocation_method": null
                                }
                            ],
                            "location": null,
                            "log_mode": null,
                            "log_path": null,
                            "name": "Ubuntu915",
                            "open_ports": null,
                            "os_type": "Linux",
                            "password": null,
                            "private_ip_address": null,
                            "private_ip_allocation_method": "Dynamic",
                            "profile": null,
                            "public_ip": true,
                            "public_ip_address_name": null,
                            "public_ip_allocation_method": "Dynamic",
                            "resource_group": "test-resource-group",
                            "secret": null,
                            "security_group": "/subscriptions/123456789/resourceGroups/test-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/fortify_testing_temp_8",
                            "state": "present",
                            "subnet_name": "default",
                            "subscription_id": null,
                            "tags": null,
                            "tenant": null,
                            "virtual_network": "testing-vm_group-vnet"
                        }
                    },
                    "msg": "value of public_ip_allocation_method must be one of: Dynamic, Static, got: None found in ip_configurations"
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the registered json using [json_modify.py](https://github.com/integr8ly/installation/blob/master/library/json_modify.py) and manually specified `Dynamic` for the key.

```
- json_modify:
      data: "{{ azure_network_interface_info }}"
      pointer: "/networkinterfaces/0/ip_configurations/0"
      action: update
      update: { "public_ip_allocation_method": "Dynamic", "public_ip_address": "{{ azure_ip.publicipaddresses[0].ip_address }}", "public_ip_address_name": "{{ public_ip_address }}" }
    register: azure_network_interface_info_modified
```